# UINavigationContoller(rootViewController: ViewController()) inside SceneDelegate Xcode 15.0 programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I can't get a result like in the screenshoot. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYa3Y.png)
Here is an example of my code inside of SceneDelegate

**SceneDelegate**

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

   var window: UIWindow?
   
   func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
    window?.windowScene = windowScene
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
   }
}
```

Unfortunately I can't get the expected result. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0RVG.png)
Please help me to understand the structure of making app with UiNavController inside SceneDelegate. I'm learning to make the apps only programmatically **without StoryBoard**
Version of Xcode is 15.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let scene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene)
        window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light // for light mode supported only 
        window?.rootViewController = BaseNavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

the base navigationController is

```
import UIKit

class BaseNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            navigationBarAppearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
            navigationBarAppearance.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "NavBarBg") // if wanna add bg image 
            navigationBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .white // white bar color
            
            UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
            UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
            UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
            navigationBar.tintColor = .white
            navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        }
    }
}
```